# Why the input resistance of a common emitter amplifier is like this?

Tags: bjt, resistance, impedance, common-emitter

I am trying to find the input resistance of this BJ common-emitter amplifier:

[image]

I replace the transistor with the hybrid-pi model

[image]

It appears clear to me that the input impedance will be

\$ R_{in} = R_1 // R_2 // (R_E + r_\pi) \$

but some authors say

\$ R_{in} = R_1 // R_2 // h_{FE}(R_E + r_\pi) \$

What is the correct value?

Comment: Have you tried to do the analysis yourself?  As a first approximation use this $$R_{IN} \approx R_1||R_2||(r_\pi + (h_{FE}+1)\cdot R_E) $$

Comment: Both are wrong. (G36 was some seconds earlier than me).

Comment: My recommendation: Do not (blindly) rely on some obscure internet contributions. Instead, use a good text book and/or do your own calculations.

Comment: @G36 - where do I find the explanation about this formula?

Comment: SpaceDog_you can derive the result by simple inspection of the circuit - if you consider the fact, that the current through RE is larger by the factor (1+beta) if compared with the current into the base node.

Comment: ok, I see that the emitter current is (1+beta) the base current, what I don't see is why RE has to be multiplied by (beta+1). If you can post an answer, I will be glad to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Think about how the gradient of the diode changes (the inverse of the transconductance) as you insert a tiny increase of base current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw this small-signal equivalent circuit:

\$R_{IN} = \frac{V_X}{I_B}\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdQlBE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And we can see that \$R_{IN} = \frac{V_X}{I_B}\$

$$V_X = I_B\cdot r_\pi + I_ER_E = I_B\cdot r_\pi + (I_B + I_C )R_E = I_B\cdot r_\pi + (I_B + h_{FE}I_C )R_E
  $$
$$=I_B\cdot r_\pi +I_B(h_{FE}+1)R_E$$

Therefore

\$R_{IN} = \frac{V_X}{I_B} =r_\pi + (h_{FE}+1)R_E\$

Or simply think about emitter current

\$I_E = I_B + I_C = I_B + \beta I_C = I_B(\beta+1) \$

Try read this 
http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/412/handouts/5.6%20Small%20Signal%20Operation%20and%20Models/section%205_6%20%20Small%20Signal%20Operation%20and%20Models%20lecture.pdf

Comment: Now I see. THANKS. Just one question: why is the upper part of the current source connected to ground?

Comment: Because we are interested in AC dynamic resistance only we use the superposition principle and we turn-off all DC-voltage sources ( set all DC sources to zero).  Look at this answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/298560/common-source-jfet-small-signal-equivalent-circuit/298571#298571

Comment: OK, I was suspecting that. Just checking...  Thanks again.