# Where does the input resistance formula of a BJT amplifier come from?

Tags: amplifier, bjt, resistance, small-signal

[image: Described Problem]

I just solved the (a) question of this problem from one of my past exams. And I am a bit confused on to why the solution is as follows:

R<sub>in</sub> = 100kΩ || R<sub>ib</sub>

R<sub>ib</sub> = (r<sub>π</sub> + (1 + β)Re)

And the way R<sub>ib</sub> is derived is using this equation:

V<sub>b</sub> = r<sub>π</sub>i<sub>b</sub> + (i<sub>b</sub> + βi<sub>b</sub>)R<sub>e</sub>

R<sub>ib</sub> = V<sub>b</sub> / i<sub>b</sub> = [r<sub>π</sub>i<sub>b</sub> + (i<sub>b</sub> + βi<sub>b</sub>)R<sub>e</sub>] / i<sub>b</sub> = (r<sub>π</sub> + (1 + β)Re)

Now, what I don't understand: Why is the input resistance R<sub>ib</sub> = V<sub>b</sub> / i<sub>b</sub>? Where did that come from? Is that derived from the Thevenin equivalent of the BJT?

Comment: How would you define the input resistance of a BJT seen from the base into transistor than? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/407868/why-the-input-resistance-of-a-common-emitter-amplifier-is-like-this/407877#407877

Comment: To complete the picture (verification based on system theory with beta=hfe and rpi=hie)): With (1+hfe)=ge (transconductance ge=d(Ie)/d(Vbe)) we arrive at r,ib=hie(1+geRe). What we can see now is how signal feedback (caused by Re) increases the input resistance of the B-E path (hie) by the factor (1+loop gain). This is in full accordance with sysytem theory.

Answer (score 1):

This is only Ohm‘s law. Vb is the voltage loss from base input to ground. Taking the current passing this line and using Ohms law, you get the resulting resistance. This resistance is parallel to 100k.[image]