# Why is Rc parallel to RL?

Tags: biasing

While determing the AC load line, the author takes Rc to be parallel to Rl. How is it possible since the two resistors have different nodes?

[image]

Comment: Please inline images, or reproduce the circuit schematic using the on-site schematic tool.

Comment: Where is the tool?

Comment: When editing your question, there should be an icon at the top with a little circuit diagram and a pencil. Click that.

Comment: I am using a phone so can't see

Comment: Try read here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/298560/common-source-jfet-small-signal-equivalent-circuit/298571#298571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the small signal analysis, you need to replace the DC power source by ground because a DC component has no AC component.

The next thing you do is replace the capacitor by short circuit. Doing so, your circuit looks like :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffWfkM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now you can see both of the resistor's nodes are connected to BJT's collector and the ground. So, they are in parallel.

Comment: How can we determine the current through El in this case? Is it Ie or Ic?

Comment: When two resistors share a common node, they are in parallel if seen from this common node and they are in series if seen from one of the "outer" nodes.

Answer (score 2):

When performing small-signal analysis, DC sources have no AC component so their variation  in time is zero i.e. they represent a short circuit, towards ground in this case.

Therefore, \$R_C\$ and \$R_L\$ share the same potentials: the BJT collector and ground.

Comment: I don't understand. Which DC source are you talking about?

Comment: @user29463: \$V_{cc}\$ in your case.